# Will the Blocks run in parallel?

Tags: cuda, gpu

The Kernel will search the 2D Array for the Number **5**

e.g Array has dimensions 10x10
, total elements = 10000 , if I divide it by  4, the Range = 2500;

BlockIdx.x = 0 then it will search (i = 0; i < 2500; i++)

BlockIdx.x = 1 then it will search (i = 2500 ; i < 5000; i++)

BlockIdx.x = 2 then it will search (i = 5000 ; i < 7500; i++)

BlockIdx.x = 3 then it will search (i = 7500 ; i < 10000; i++)

```
Kernel Code 
__global__
void psearch(int *d_array)
{

int blockID = blockIdx.x;
int condition = (blockID+1)*(Range)

for(int i = blockID*(Range) ; i < condition; i++)
{
    if(d_array[i] == 5)
    {
        d_array[1] = 1992;
    }
}
```

As can be seen below, I am calling the kernel with 4 blocks of 1 thread each.

```
Kernel Call
psearch<<<4,1>>>(d_array);
```

My question is the kernel call will call 4 blocks of 1 thread each, so I can say that all the blocks are running in parallel and therefore the Array is being searched in parallel.

Device Name = Quadro FX 1800M

This program is for learning purposes, so if i made any mistakes, I will be glad if you people could point them out.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Can you say the array is being searched in parallel?  Yes, you can say the array is being searched in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will run in parallel, however it will be underperforming grately compared to what you card is actually capable to do. In order to harvest whole power you should have at least:

- as many blocks as there are stream multiprocessors (should be fine for your particular model)
- have at least 32 threads in a block, preferably more than 128.

GPUs get their performance when you have hundreds or thousands of threads. 4 is very, very little for a GPU.